# Don't stop a request on timeout in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to implement a function that returns `Observable`, sends a request to a server and waits a response for some time. If response is not received during this time, `Observable` emits value from some variable/cache. But after the response is received, `Observable` emits again, but with the real response. If the response was received in time, `Observable` emits only one value (the real response).

At first I tried to use `timeout` operator, but the problem is this operator interrupts the request and throw the exception. Right now my solution looks terrible. Can I do it in one pipe?

My current code:

`let subject = new Subject();
    let finished = false;

```
let request = this.http.post(`/url`)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => {
      finished = true;
    }),
  ).subscribe((x) => subject.next(x));


timer(3000).subscribe(() => {
  if (!finished) {
      console.log("FROM BUFFER");
      subject.next(bufferedItem);
    }
  }
});

return subject;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If its a timeout configured by you, you can have [timeout](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html) inside pipe itself :

```
  pipe(
        timeout(2500),
        catchError(error => of(`Request timed out after: ${duration}`))
      )
```

2) If its a gateway timeout, you can return response from your **catchError** block, or [retry](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retrywhen.html) based on the conditions

3) **Timer** will run every 3 secs as per your code and dispatch event, use timeout instead inside pipe

4) Subscribe to the actual response once received and send response finally.

Comment: The timeout is configured by me. As I've written, `timemout` will interrupt my request, but I don't want to do it. As for the 3rd statement, I agree, is my bad.